# Issue if polled on listening socket instead of binding fd

Tags: c, sockets, polling

In a TCP server/client, we do polling on binding fd  (fd received during socket connection and binded to some IP). I am wondering what will be the impact if we do polling on listening socket (socket fd received during accept call)? Will polling on listening socket can anyway have issue related to close_wait state socket issue? 
Sample code below:-

```
struct pollfd pfd;

pfd.fd = sockfd; /*listening socket fd got during accept call*/
pfd.events = POLLIN;

ret = poll(&pfd, 1, 60000);

if (ret == 0 || errno == EINTR) {

    *err = SOCKET_ERR_READ_TIMEOUT;
    *size = 0; 
    return SOCKET_FAILURE;

}else if (ret < 0) { 
    close(sockfd);
    return SOCKET_FAILURE;
}

ret = recv(sockfd, content, *size , 0);

if (ret == -1) {

    close(sockfd);
    *size = 0;
    return SOCKET_FAILURE;

} else if (ret == 0) {
    close(sockfd);
    *size = 0;
    return SOCKET_FAILURE;
}

*size = ret;

return SOCKET_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: I am very sorry to tell you this, but I cannot understand your question. In particular, "Will polling on listening socket can anyway have issue" makes no sense to me. Could you please try a different wording?

Comment: There is nothing special or unusual in the code you show, that is one common way how you poll a socket to wait for data to arrive on it with a timeout. The only thing is that `poll` will block for at most 60 seconds, possibly stopping your entire program from doing anything else. If you're only accepting one connection at a time that is fine, but if you want to be able to handle multiple connection that's not possible without the help of threads.

Comment: My concern is what if client has closed the polling socket and server is  still polling on the same socket? Won't as per my sample code, polling may return zero where I am not closing the listening socket and returning from the function.(First if condition check in the sample code). Won't this lead to close_wait state for the socket as this socket is not closed anywhere on the server side even when client has closed the socket?

Comment: If the other end has closed the connection then the socket on your side will become readable, and `poll` will return with that status set.

Comment: For the naming used: "*listening socket fd got during accept call*" I feel this is a contradictory expression. `accept()` takes a listening socket and returns another socket, the accepted one. The "listening" socket could be named the "bound", as it had been bound using `bind()`, prior to being passed to `listen()` and `accept()`.

Comment: OT: `errno == EINTR` does not indicate a time-out.